# How to remove "WIP" flag from a git branch

Tags: git, zsh

I pushed a branch on the remote and the commit message started with "WIP".
Now my prompt displays "wip" no matter what branch I am on.
I'm using zsh with power10k theme, if this has any relevance.
How can I remove that flag? I tried reverting the commit, and I also created a new branch, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Do you also see the _wip_ in the output of `git branch --show-current`? If not, it's something produced by your PROMPT, but you did not show us your PROMPT definition.

Comment: It went away when I committed others changes with a message not starting by "wip".

Comment: So we know at least that the "culprit" (or more likely: "feature") was the way you defined your PROMPT....